# UIActivity indicator when used as Uitableview footer displays stretched in device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Am using UIActivity indicator as UItableviewfooter,
my code is shown here

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 spinner.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44);
[spinner startAnimating];

self.myTableView.tableFooterView=spinner;
```

this works quite well in simulator, but when i run it in device the activity indicator seems stretched in both axis as per the cell dimensions .

Comment: All that i need is to display activity indicator at the foot of my UItableview, while loading the cells.Tried adding an extra cell and adding activity indicator as subview, but the problems repeats again....only when i use it in device. Any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
spinner.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44);
```

Probably because you're setting the width of the activity spinner as 310 pts. Instead, set it to 44 (to make the frame square), and adjust the x origin parameter to center it.

I'm not able to test this at the moment, but it'd probably be in the form of:

```
CGFloat activityWidth = 44;
CGFloat activityHeight = 44;
CGFloat tableFooterViewWidth = self.myTableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.width;

spinner.frame=CGRectMake(tableFooterViewWidth - (activityWidth/2),
                         0,
                         activityWidth,
                         activityHeight);
```

Comment: +1.  @Deepak - that 310 is probably something like the y coordinate of the position of the spinner, not the size as you have it.  But how to get the footer position?  WDUK has it at 0.0.  I think you want something like this: MAX(tableViewView.contentSize.height, tableView.frame.size.height); as an offset in your tableView coordinate system.